# Laws between humans and anthropomorphic dragons (WIP / Questions)

Tags: society, law, fire, races, inequality

I am currently creating a society for a short CG film. My main character is a young a,thropomorphic dragon living in the same standards as humans (as you can see on the image). I would have wanted to upload a larger image but >2MB limit.

[image]

As the society is contemporary, laws have been written to make everyone coexist. However, some differences wtill exist and my main character will attempt to start a political campaign to calm society.

Humans and dragons are sometimes rude to each other, as one species has scales rather than skin, and some jobs are hardly accessbile to dragons as they have only 4 fingers, but achieve the same precisoin as humans in a wide variety of domains.

However, the most important problem of this society is related to **fire.** Dragons can still spit fire as their ancestors, but in waaay smaller quantities than before, as their size has diminished over time. Fire also demand a great physical effort from them. Due to this ability, humans and them have created a law saying that fire can only be used in life-death situations ( E.G. you can't turn the barbecue on in a cool way), and can never be considered as self-defence.

Some people (dragons at 95%), but less than 2 or 3% of the population want to contest this law, saying hat the restritction of fire use is another loss of rights.

Would this law be able to survive?

Comment: I am afraid this is about the plot of your story, not about the rules of your world. Please take a look at the [help] for more info.

Comment: 'can only be used in life-or-death situations and can never be considered self-defense'? So, if someone is attacking a dragon and gets fire-breathed, that person is now able to sue the dragon because fire breath isn't self-defense? And if the dragon had, say, *shot* the person with a gun, that would be totally fine?

Comment: In cas eof an agression, it all depends on damage dealt on both sides. If for exaple the dragon only has minor injury, but the human has a 2nd degree burn, there is a point for the human in court. If, at inverse, the human is not even burned but the dragon has like a whole set of 45 scales ripped off, then point for draogn in court.  Otherwise, laws of our world apply. Gun-related laws are the same as in France, where I am. I d'ont really knwo much stuff about law sin other countries, except taht some still have death penalty.

Comment: Sorry for spelling errors, I am trying to type really fast but I press space too early.

Comment: *"If for exaple the dragon only has minor injury, but the human has a 2nd degree burn, there is a point for the human in court":* This is **not** how self-defence works, in any country of this world. The success of a self-defence assertion depends on the *perceived danger*, not on the injuries actually sustained. If a thug comes at me with a knife and I kill him somehow, I can assert self-defence although he is dead and I am alive and not even scratched. That is to say, if a reasonable dragon would believe that their life was in danger, then killing the threat with fire is justified.

Comment: Wow... You are a hundred percent right. I don't know how I could improve this law, but I need to get self defense out of there. Which restrictions could be applied?

Comment: P.S. I think i will name it "Article 451" ; )

Comment: I'd say it's hard to imagine such a law being enacted in the first place, but look at Jim Crow, Prohibition, etc. It's pretty hard to imagine it *lasting*, however; it's about as purposeful as outlawing matches, or making it illegal to construct a bow drill.

Comment: The problem behind the creation of this law is that the humans had the need to feel superior, and this is what my character will attempt to demonstrate. Humans have longed for powers, and seeing another species as intelligent as them able to spit fire without any damage (therfore being fire resistant), made them jealous towards them, even over the course of centuries. They may be able to spit fire, but learning accurate modeling and precision thake longer for dragons, due to their lack of a finger. This is not blatant jealousness, such as fighting over each other.

Comment: In fact, jealousaness works longer when it is more subtle, and this is what humans have understood. By making this law, they ensure a longer time of estalbishment of a pseudo-superiority.

Answer (score 0):

What is the population distribution between humans and dragons? 50-50?

Are there tensions and animosity between humans and dragons? Is one race richer and higher status than the other on average?

Is this a 21st century style western democracy? What is the repress of dragons in the government?

Do the two races live evenly mixed everywhere or are they geographically separated to a significant extent?

Why are the dragons adamant about being allowed to breathe fire? Is it a physical or psychological need, or is it tied to important draconian cultural practices?

On that note: Do humans and dragons share a culture or do they have each their own culture, religion and the like?

Comment: The proprtion of humans-dragons is 65h - 35d. Technically, there are no tensions between them as they have lived for centuries, at least that's what the governement says. There are dragons working in governments, but a higher proportion of humans than the population (90h - 10d ≠  65h - 35d). Dragons have their own language, but they use it only in family cricles or in between them. There is a faire share of people understanding the 2 languages, as they are both taught in schools. No cultural practices are present, but I'll think I'll create a relaigion for dragons

Comment: But religion is a sensitive subject, and referencing it is a risky initiative, at least, thats how i see it. I won't think I'll show a church or any religious building in the film i plan about creating

Comment: Why do the dragons object so much to this law? Why are they so attached to their right to breathe fire?

Comment: @PaulTIKI wrong spiel you did it on an answer! although both our answerer and asker are both new!

Comment: You are correct.  I was just going through the first time posts queue